# WPF display listview item in a Image control

Tags: wpf, listview

I have a `Listview` and next to it an `Image` control. I have set `CollectionOfCapturedImages` for my `Listview`'s ItemsSource.

```
public ObservableCollection<BitmapImage> CollectionOfCapturedImages { get; } = new ObservableCollection<BitmapImage>();

<ListView x:Name="testListView" ItemsSource="{Binding CollectionOfCapturedImages}" MouseLeftButtonDown="testListView_MouseLeftButtonDown" Height="345"  Margin="567,10,10,0" VerticalAlignment="Top">
            <ListView.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <UniformGrid Columns="1" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemsPanel>
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                        <Image Source="{Binding}" Height="150" Width="150"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
```

How could I display selected `Listview` item (`BitmapImage`) in my `Image` control?
I have tried to add `MouseLeftButtonDown="testListView_MouseLeftButtonDown"`

```
private void testListView_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            newlyAddedImage.Source = testListView.SelectedItem;
        }
```

how can I get this working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try to just bind the `Source` property of the `Image` to the `SelectedItem` property of the `ListView`?

```
<Image x:Name="newlyAddedImage" Source="{Binding SelectedItem, ElementName=testListView}" />
```